Error: invalid solidity type!: tuple
I have an error code while doing unit testing to a contract:
Error: invalid solidity type!: tuple
The line that throw the error is:
const negotiation = await this.negotiations.allNegotiations("0");
The relevant parts of the code are:

struct Negotiation {
    address lender;
    address borrower;
    uint256 timestamp;
    uint8 status;
}

Negotiation[] private _allNegotiations;

function allNegotiations(uint256 index) external view override returns (Negotiation memory) {
    return _allNegotiations[index];
}

Seems like has something to do with web3 library being unable to handle structs as function returns, so I am attaching my hardhat config and package.json just in case this is related to web3 versioning:
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle4");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify");
require("solidity-docgen");
const { infuraApiKey, mnemonic, etherscanApiKey } = require('./secrets.json');

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.24",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  docgen: {
    path: './docs',
    clear: true,
    runOnCompile: true
  },
  networks: {
    /* Arbitrum - Sepolia */
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://arbitrum-sepolia.infura.io/v3/${infuraApiKey}`,
      accounts: { mnemonic: mnemonic },
    },
    hardhat: {
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: etherscanApiKey
  },
  sourcify: {
    enabled: true
  }
};

package.json:
{
  "name": "smart-contracts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protocol",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.6",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle4": "^2.0.6",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-web3-legacy": "^2.0.0",
    "ethers": "^6.13.0",
    "web3": "^0.20.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^2.0.8",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^5.0.2",
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.16",
    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "hardhat": "^2.18.3",
    "solidity-docgen": "^0.6.0-beta.36",
    "web3-utils": "^4.3.0"
  }
}

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

You seem to be using quite older version of web3.js library as shown by your devDependencies in the package.json file:
"devDependencies": {
    // other dev dependencies
    "web3": "^0.20.7"
}

Instead, you should use v4.x.x, the latest version at this point in time is v4.10.0.
So, uninstalling and reinstalling again, should do the work:
npm uninstall web3
npm install web3

